# CSS wordpress second level sub menu items disappear on hover

Tags: css

Using a blank Wordpress theme to create a custom site, but it did not have any CSS for a drop down submenu. I have it basically working but when I try to move the cursor to the second drop down item down under the (events tab) the sub menu disappears.

[site is here](http://newpathwaysretreat.com)

I thought I have it all set to display block so that the whole menu item is the button, but not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the z-index of the drop down menu higher than the image. By default elements have a z-index of 1, so anything greater than 1 will do (unless you've specified otherwise)

Comment: I did try that, I set the nav ul ul to have a z-index:99999 (same as the twentyeleven theme) still does not do the trick.